# Modify an Linked Object?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm doing an online course right now and can't seem to get one thing right.

In the course, an object is used as a reference to influence the linked objects together. Which works fine.

But on the picture you can see that a linked object has a 90 degree angle. I can't get this to work in Blender. If I change one linked object, the others change with it.

How do I get this to work?[image: Linked Object]

On the other hand,he uses a volume box to make this 90 degree angle look like a bevel on an Linked Object.

How is this done in Blender?

[[image: Volume box]][12]

Comment: Hello :). Do you mean linked objects sharing the same mesh? Please add more info and perhaps a link to the video.

Comment: Exactly. The large mesh in the background serves as a reference. If you change something in this mesh, it will be transferred to all other meshes. The only problem is that the individual meshes cannot be changed without it being transferred to the others. I could unlink the mesh, of course, but that completely defeats the purpose. How do I edit individual meshes that are linked without affecting the others?

Comment: Perhaps you're rotating the object in EDIT mode, therefore modifying your mesh, as opposed to rotating it in OBJECT mode? **TAB** key toggles between those modes.